# CUDA Fortran: Cannot copy array of arrays(or array of pointers to arrays) using cudaMemCpy

Tags: cuda

I am trying to compile a basic memory transfer code using PGI's fortran compiler(Workstation/PGI Visual Fortran). The compiler throws an error on the line where I have a cudamemcpy call. The exact error message is "Could not resolve generic procedure cudamemcpy" for the line

```
istat=cudaMemcpy(arr(1),arr(2),800,cudaMemcpyDevicetoDevice)
```

I am also using the cuda fortran module--"use cudafor". What's the solution to this compiler error? Thanks!

Comment: What is `arr`? What is `800`? I know what it is _supposed_ to be in the context of CUDA, I am interested in what those values mean to you application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arrays arr(1) and arr(2) are of type

```
type subgrid
   integer, device, dimension(:,:,:), allocatable :: field
end type subgrid
```

The problem was resolved by not using the 4th argument and by specifying the actual field data that needed to be transferred. 800 is the number of integers I needed to be transferred from one slice to the other.

```
istat=cudaMemcpy(arr(1)%field(:,:,:), arr(2)%field(:,:,:), 800)
```

Also, the cudaMemcpyDevicetoDevice doesn't affect the function call. It works fine with/without it.